# Unable to get Facebook to pick up logo when linked

Tags: html, facebook

I'm unable to get Facebook or Google+ to pick up my site's logo when I try to link the URL.  The site is: -url removed-

The logo is the only image linked to on the site that isn't a background image.  Any suggestions on why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) your page (`http://domain.com`) has an `og:url` tag pointing to `http://www.domain.com` which itself has an `og:url` tag pointing to `http://www.www.domain.com` which according to a quick check in CURL doesn't have the appropriate meta tags.

Comment: Despite passing the debug tool... it still isn't showing the image when I try to post the link to Facebook.